# try-catch exception handling java

Tags: java, exception

I was on the way to finish this but some rollback happaned, so when I am trying to write in text file using try-catch it gives me such error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

It is pointing to this line :

```
output.format("%-10s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%n", ....
```

I read that can happen because the object referenced is `null` or something. But before the output line I tried to output  all values with `system.out.println()` , and there was no problem with that.

Is there some solution to that ?

```
try {
    record.setIncome(input.nextDouble());

record.setAtv(atv_sum);
record.setSumAtv(atv_sum+45.00);
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");

double soc_apd=(((record.getIncome()-record.getSumAtv())/simt)*soc_proc);
double iedz=((((record.getIncome()-record.getSumAtv()-soc_apd))/simt)*iedz_proc);
df.format(iedz);
double netto =record.getIncome()-(iedz+soc_apd);

if((record.getIncome()>=min_alga)){
    output.format("%-10s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%n",
        year_n,
        months[month_n],                        
        df.format(record.getIncome()),
        df.format(record.getAtv()),
        df.format(record.getSumAtv()),
        df.format(iedz),
        df.format(soc_apd),
        df.format(netto));
}else{
    String error_1 = "KÄ¼Å«da ! Alga ievadÄ«ta zem 0 vai minimÄ?lÄ?s algas  "+min_alga+" LS";
    System.err.println(error_1);
    input.nextLine();
}           
}
catch ( FormatterClosedException formatterClosedException ){
    System.err.println(error_2);
    return;
}
catch (NoSuchElementException elementException){
    System.err.println(error_3);
    input.nextLine();
}
```

I found which record couses the problem . Output is like this:

so the  `df.format(record.getIncome())` couses the problem

```
2013
45.0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at course.CreateTextFile.addRecords(CreateTextFile.java:163)
    at course.calc.CreateTextFileTest(calc.java:16)
    at course.calc.main(calc.java:33)
321.468
165.55
1062.982
1550.0
```

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but have you defined the variable 'output' elsewhere?

Comment: Might be something within df.format(..) is null ...

Comment: *"because the object referenced is null or something"* Without something.

Comment: where is output instantiated ? It needs to be something before it is used

Comment: The line that you're now saying causes the problem is different to the line you said it was before..? In any case, the answers below are correct: one of your objects is null; there's no way for us to know which one, so it's up to you to find it.

Comment: @Boann I found that problem is File object that should create file. Everything else works just great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **debug and verify that which object is `null`** from following line... possibilities are.. e.g. `months, output` etc

```
output.format("%-10s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%n",
                                    year_n,
                                    months[month_n],                        
                                    df.format(record.getIncome()),
                                    df.format(record.getAtv()),
                                    df.format(record.getSumAtv()),
                                    df.format(iedz),
                                    df.format(soc_apd),
                                    df.format(netto));
                                         }
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably because `output` itself is null? You wouldn't get a nullpointer if one of the variables you're printing is null, because it would just print the text 'null'. But for the arguments that you are formatting with `df` you would. So those are some likely candidates. This is as simply as debugging through your code and checking what is null.

Btw, I don't even see output declared but it's likely it's supposed to be a String. In that case it would not matter that output is null, because `format` is a static method. You should access the method format in a static way though, i.e. `String.format`

So, to summarize:

- Show us what `output` is.
- If `output` is a String, access `format` in a static way.
- Learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: `months` also could be null...

Comment: @EugenHalca: No because then it would show the nullpointer on that line instead.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek I updated answer, so the formating couses the problem ?

Comment: Only if you're trying to format a null value. And thanks for inserting the stack trace but since we don't know your line numbers it doesn't tell us much. But I guess we can assume that it's record.getIncome() that returns a null value then. Have you checked this?

Comment: @Eugen Halca Problem is with object that creates file because when I create manually the file specified, it works, but when I delete it it trows java.lang.NullPointerException